# How to set the Background image for window in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I want to set a background image for a Tkinter window, I've created a root window

```
import Tkinter
root=Tkinter.Tk()
```

How to set the background image for "root" window ?

Can we set any type of image as background(.png or .mpeg)?

If image is not of the window size, how to fit that image onto entire window?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create a [`Tk.PhotoImage`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) instance and set a label's image attribute to that PhotoImage. Any other widgets created should be manually positioned using the `place` or `grid` methods to make them above the image label. To resize the image to fit the window, you would want to use PIL's [`Image.resize()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) function.

Comment: To set the background image for the label, we can set its image property during creation, but TK() dont have that property right?

Comment: The image property is of the label.

Comment: but, i want to set the background image for window

Comment: @Raj The label will be as big as the window.

Comment: @Ramachandra Thank you, But cant we put background to original root window itself?, Is that a missing feature in Tkinter?

Comment: @Raj I don't know any GUI toolkit which has that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the frame has an image parameter, but I found a satisfying answer here :

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/491009/set-an-image-as-a-tkinter-window-background

This is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file = "bg.gif")
w = Label(root, image=photo)
w.pack()
ent = Entry(root)
ent.pack()
ent.focus_set() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I don't know if the frame has an image parameter,"_ - no, it does not.